# svn diff in a batch file

Tags: svn, scripting, batch-file, diff

I am trying to obtain the number of lines changed between two two revisions of a file using the svn diff command. My code is as follows:

```
svn diff "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk" --revision 923475:925738 >>output.txt
```

When i open up a cmd window and run this, it works fine. Now, I am a beginner in batch scripting and not familiar with it. As I understand it, if i copy and paste the above command into a .bat file and then run that .bat file, i should get the same output. However, when i tried this, what happens is that it writes the following to the output text file in a never ending loop.

C:\Users\Desktop>svn diff "http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk" --revision 923475:925738  1>>output.txt

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or show me how to use the svn diff command inside a batch file? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Notes, not answer

- Good syntax for your command (*and task*) is

> svn diff http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk -r 923475:925738

(note none of " around URL, -r = --revision, just shorter)

- **Biggest** trouble at the same time for URL is command output

  svn: E160013: Diff target 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk' was not found in the repository at revisions '923475' and '925738'

i.e - you can't get result even in your syntax and from command-prompt

If we `svn log -q http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk | tail -2` we'll get

```
r924461 | markrmiller | 2010-03-18 01:17:26 +0500 (Чт, 18 мар 2010)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

924461 > 923475, trunk didn't exist on start revision yet

- If you want "... obtain the number of lines changed between two two revisions of a file...", you have to define **this file** in URL, dev/trunk is directory with a lot of files
- output.txt will be giant multiMB file with diffs without needed you data

> how to use the svn diff command inside a batch file?

Same way as it performed in command prompt by hand (only one detail - when you work with WC, don't forget cd to it or use full path to WC inside bat-file)

Comment: sorry, i did not understand what you meant by WC? which directory do i need to include the full path of inside the bat file?